# Create bookmark off of DEFAULT in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

We use Mercurial and are not allowed to create named branches, only bookmarks for separate development.   Only the DEFAULT branch must exist in our upstream repo.

My understanding of bookmarks comes primarily from [this page](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-bookmarks), so I may be missing something.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a bookmark directly off the DEFAULT tip.   In order to get the bookmark tip (say, MYREV) to be different than the DEFAULT tip, it seems like I must go one revision back and create the bookmark from there.

Is there a way to create a bookmark directly off of the DEFAULT tip revision and have it be a separate tip?

Comment: you probably mean *named* branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create your bookmark on the tip; creating a bookmark makes it the *active* bookmark, and it'll automatically be updated to follow new commits:

```
$ hg book new_bookmark_name
$ hg commit -m 'change message'
```

An active bookmark will simply be moved over to the new commit; any other bookmarks are left in place. Only one bookmark is active at a given time.

You can always make an existing bookmark active by updating your working copy to it:

```
$ hg up bookmark_name  # make bookmark_name active
```

Bookmarks in Mercurial are just like bookmarks in books in the physical world; easily moved to another page. If your local bookmark wasn't active but you made a new commit, manually point the bookmark to your new commit:

```
$ hg book --force -r . bookmark_name
```

The above command forces `bookmark_name` to point to the working directory parent revision.

You don't *have* to have a bookmark; local revisions naturally form a branch; bookmarks just make it easier to keep track of such commits. Bookmarks are also just simple pointers; a name pointing to a specific revision. You can always update them to point to another revision.

Answer (score -2):

> we use Mercurial and are not allowed to create branches

that's an oxymoron. Using Mercurial means that you can do whatever you want with your local copy of a repository. That's the whole point of a distributed code versioning system!

Whoever set that policy didn't fully (or even nearly understand) mercurial. Luckily, since this is your own copy of the repository, you can do whatever you want, and the policy is unenforcable.

So, and this is honestly my answer to your question: You're trying to build branches with bookmarks. Don't. Just simply use branches. You can bookmark tips of branches, should your strange manager pop up and ask for bookmarks.

Comment: Sorry, it's an official policy, way above my pay grade.   That is the rule, no branches committed to the upstream repo.   Don't ask me why, I just work there.

Comment: Branch information is part of the commit, so pushing this commit to another repository won't magically place it on the default branch.

Comment: As Martijn Pieters said, the branch name is stored in the commit.  However, you *can* simply transplant commits.  I don't actually recommend this and have not tried it, but in theory you could entirely automate this with the Convert extension: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension (you'd have to use an extra repository for staging the converted-to-default commits).